# Venues of the Tokyo 2020 Olympics competitions

Tags: data-request, geospatial, sports, japan

The Tokyo 2020 Olympics & Paralympics competitions will presumably be held at many stadiums and other sport venues.

Is there a list of them?

Necessary details for each venue:

- Name of the venue in English
- Name of the venue in Japanese
- Latitude/longitude
- Sports the venue is used for

An official list would be the best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [venue list](https://tokyo2020.jp/en/games/venue/) on the official page now lists venue for both Olympics and Paralympics.

[image]

Additionally, the HTML source has geographical names in addition to venue name, which should help for geocoding.

```
    <tr>
      <td class="icon"><img src="/assets/img/common/list/icon-no10.png" alt="(10)Yumenoshima, Koto-ku, Tokyo" ></td>
      <td>
          <a class="iconListQuaternary not_hover">Dream Island Archery Field</a>
      </td>
      <td>
        Archery<br>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Tokyo 2020 Olympics travel guide](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo_2020) at Wikivoyage has a list of venues:

https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Tokyo_2020#Where

Problems:

- Unofficial
- Written in prose, thus difficult to reuse
- Not sure whether complete